# How to get content of tag 'src' inside class `img`?

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I would like to extract the content of tag `src` from such elements

```
<div class="img-placeholder" style="padding-bottom:57.9%;">
<img data-srcset="abc.png" src="abc.png" data-placeholder="blurry" alt="Kijun Line" class=" lazyloaded" data-click-tracked="true" data-img-lightbox="true" data-owner="" data-caption="TradingView" data-expand="300" id="mntl-sc-block-image_1-0-5" data-tracking-container="true" srcset="abc.png 1541w">
</div>
```

I tried `[tag.attrs['src'] for tag in soup.select('img')]` but it returns an error `KeyError: 'src'`. Could you please elaborate on why it did not work and how to fix it?

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

l = 'https://www.investopedia.com/terms/k/kijun-line.asp'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
r = session.get(l, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser') 
temp4 = [tag.attrs['src'] for tag in soup.select('img')]
temp4
```

**Update:** I change to

```
[tag.attrs['src'] for tag in soup.select('div.img-placeholder img') if 'src' in tag.attrs]
```

but the result is not as expected, i.e.

```
['data:image/gif;charset=utf-8;base64,R0lGODlhCwAGAPIAAHNzdWulg+Xy5f/l5f///3NzdXNzdXNzdSwAAAAACwAGAEIIGwAJCBxIsKDBgwIGBiAI4CABAAMGJAwQ0SHBgAA7',
 'data:image/gif;charset=utf-8;base64,R0lGODlhCgAGAPIAABisoH+O0f2zcoGRz7a/4LfA4ejp7fDw8iwAAAAACgAGAEIIIQANHBhIcKCBAQULGhCYkMCBhQkHFhDAEMCBAAQhRnwYEAA7']
```

For example, one of elements satisfying the condition is

[image]

**Update:** I change to `selenium`. It's weird that I can get only one among 2 satisfying elements. My code is

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os, time
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\Akira\\Downloads\\Compressed\\chromedriver.exe')
l = 'https://www.investopedia.com/terms/k/kijun-line.asp'
driver.get(l)
time.sleep(10)
text = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser') 
temp4 = [tag.attrs['src'] for tag in soup.select('div.img-placeholder img') if 'src' in tag.attrs]
temp4
```

The result is

```
['https://www.investopedia.com/thmb/LbG-nFJad_8ednnDsr-fD7Uvcb8=/1541x893/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc():format(webp)/Kijun-Sen-3b696ff097264a429b780a98afeb5cbe.png',
 'data:image/gif;charset=utf-8;base64,R0lGODlhCgAGAPIAABisoH+O0f2zcoGRz7a/4LfA4ejp7fDw8iwAAAAACgAGAEIIIQANHBhIcKCBAQULGhCYkMCBhQkHFhDAEMCBAAQhRnwYEAA7']
```

Comment: @RishabhKumar I also ask to clarify why my code did not work.

Comment: Seems not all of the `img` tags have a `src` attribute: `[tag.attrs['src'] for tag in soup.select('img') if 'src' in tag.attrs]`

Comment: Thank you so much @JustinEzequiel. You're right :))

Comment: @JustinEzequiel explaination seems appropriate

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries - "To check whether a single key is in the dictionary, use the in keyword."

Comment: @JustinEzequiel I have updated my code, but the result is not as expected. Could you please have a look at it?

Comment: Is the `src` present in the HTML as sent to the browser? It loooks like it might be constructed on-the-fly by JavaScript.

Comment: `data:image/gif;charset=utf-8;base64,` - the `data:...;base64` indicates that the author embedded the image directly in the HTML and not as a link to a separate resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs

Comment: @JustinEzequiel It's weird to me because I can see the link in the source (highlighted in yellow).

Comment: What you see in your browser's "view source" may not be the same as the HTML you get using requests. Your browser does javascript while `requests` does not.

Comment: You can write out `r.content` to a file that you can then view using a text editor.

Comment: Thank you so much @JustinEzequiel. I got it.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel I have just updated my thread with code using `selenium`. A weird problem happens. Could you please have a look at it?

Comment: Well, if you really do not want the images with `src="data:"` then you can just filter those out. You can though decode those using python and get an actual image file saved on your machine if that was the whole point of gathering all those image tags.

Comment: Thank you so much @JustinEzequiel. I'm curious about why I let headless chrome wait for 10 seconds, but I still can not get both links rendered by javascript.

Comment: The `data:...` links will not turn into regular `http...` links even with javascript.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel When I open the link in Chrome and wait until it is fully loaded. I can see the links `http` of both images. That's why I'm curious :))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229478/discussion-between-le-anh-dung-and-justin-ezequiel).

Comment: Busy but you can try duplicating all the request headers and cookies that your browser sends when browsing manually. My try with requests returns two images with `data:...`. My try with selenium returns only one image with `data:...`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your dedicated explanation @JustinEzequiel. I'm sorry for bothering you this much :))

Comment: Are you expecting two urls? What are they?

Comment: Hi @QHarr. For this [link](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/k/kijun-line.asp), I would like to take this [url](https://www.investopedia.com/thmb/LbG-nFJad_8ednnDsr-fD7Uvcb8=/1541x893/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc():format(webp)/Kijun-Sen-3b696ff097264a429b780a98afeb5cbe.png) of [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CS2Xj.png), and

Comment: this [url](https://www.investopedia.com/thmb/NFJHxx4Dj3HLzCiGwPO2mlQ8A5U=/5792x3376/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc():format(webp)/dotdash_Final_Kijun_Line_Base_Line_Jul_2020-01-916da09faf454d6bba208b31c2976be9.jpg) of [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRjpx.png). You can inspect these 2 images to see the urls I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the data-src attribute not the src

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.investopedia.com/terms/k/kijun-line.asp')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print([i['data-src'] for i in soup.select('.img-placeholder img')])
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine. Is there anyway to capture the link inside attribute `src`?

Comment: It is not present in the response exactly as on page. You can filter/regex out the same resolution url from the data-srcset

Comment: I'm just curious if there are some techniques to extract the content of attributre `src`. I meant the content that I see when I right click on the image and `Inspect` it in Google Chrome?

Comment: I think it is generated via javascript so you could use selenium?

Comment: You can see in my update that my solution with `selenium` did not work. Even I let headless Chrome to wait for 10 seconds so that Javascript content is fully loaded, I still can not capture the links. That makes me curious :))

Comment: Did you use the same code I out in my question? Please see my [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWG2X.png). It only captures one of 2 links.

Comment: I think it is generated within this script `https://www.investopedia.com/static/1.139.0/cache/eNqNU0FywzAI_FA1ekSvvfUFSMYONZZShOo4ry9xkjbjKGlnPAbWuxgE8kVBKXqmUPyHPZ8VZXnxF9iQqsSkhMWFSqxuJt25De2qZjguhY5YbhNMSfk9Smb-QWOe9jlh0uIpKUoC9h32KCf-6gh2LTb0vVUDio4pjU5wFtKz7MGnVhY8nP9pla7ktfY7sKUcLf_h_G6W162pTr3CDMsTSs94oMDooNlngi8aDMzJ7xA6FGfIjfuHJogxo9QplFW4iZt1iQGMV-smVPBhsZPAi2mpZuoGNKs5s9L-alvUolKjVhusi9mGnnTdmBxHF4g5ZJCu_FNIEwzoo3Wl-EbDTkM-vILkWpDvlrJYMC5uJH0yj9PmPpjF9mRKrhKxbONnxwOdU7Bpr3t68f8YoS3jZFcO5Nf7BqcoaTY.min.js:formatted` with `function h(e, t)`

Comment: Thank you for your information, but my question is why my headless chrome could not capture such links.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229588/discussion-between-qharr-and-le-anh-dung).